# Открывающийся и закрывающийся блок на jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

Всем привет. Есть несколько таких блоков

```js
$(".btn_more1").click(function() {
  $(this).prev("div.ctn_more1").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```css
.ctn_more1 {
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ctn_more1">1</div>
<button class="btn_more1">Подробнее</button></div>

<div class="ctn_more1">2</div>
<button class="btn_more1">Подробнее2</button></div>
```

Т.е. его максимальная высота 40px, при нажатии на кнопку должна открываться вниз, на всю высоту.Но он закрывает и открывает только на вот эти 40 px. Как сделать, что-бы отрабатывала на всю высоту. Плюс еще вопрос, как сделать так что-бы в блоке последняя строчка как бы исчезала медленно? А то тут явно обрывается текст, что не очень красиво.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте что-то вроде:

```
$(".btn_more1").click(function() {
  $(this).prev("div.ctn_more1").toggleClass('ctn_more2');
});
```

а в классе ctn_more2 например указать высоту 300px (или другую)

Comment: единственное что без анимации смотрится так себе. Но это можно дописать отдельно.

Answer (score 0):

Пример: https://codepen.io/romkaa/pen/VyQPpv

Просто убери вообще значение высоты. Если ты используешь slideToggle - это тебе не нужно.

На счет обрезания текста, я бы добавлял еще класс дополнительный, у которого сделал бы after псевдоэлемент, где просто через прозрачность плавно закрашивал бы текст.

Код

```
.ctn_more1 {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px 0 10px;
}

.ctn_more1::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); 
}
```